# How to identify the tables which are vacuum is disabled

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

How do I identify tables which are vacuum disabled at the table level?

Answer (score 2):

That information is stored in the column [`pg_class.reloptions`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html). That column is an array containing `key=value` pairs.

To find those where autovacuum has been disabled, you can use:

```
select relnamespace::regnamespace as schema_name, 
       relname as table_name
from pg_class 
where 'autovacuum_enabled=false' = any(reloptions);
```

<sup>(I can't test it, but that should work with 9.4 as well)</sup>